# Restrict field values to either 1 or 0 in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to restrict the value entered for the form field 'active' to either 0 or 1, 0 being inactive and 1 being active

The code that is inserting the user in the database:

```
if ($_POST['active'] != '1' || $_POST['active'] != '0') {
    $errors[] = 'Active field can only take values of either 1 or 0';
} else {
        if (empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors) === true) {
            $register_data = array(
                'username'      => $_POST['username'],
                'password'      => $_POST['password'],
                'first_name'    => $_POST['first_name'],
                'email'         => $_POST['email'],
                'active'        => $_POST['active'],
                );
            admin_add_user($register_data);
            header('Location: add_user.php?success');
            exit();
        } 
        else if (empty($errors) === false) {
            echo output_errors($errors);
        }
}
```

The function:

```
function admin_add_user($register_data) {
    include('core/db/db_connection.php');
    array_walk($register_data, 'array_sanitize'); 
    $register_data['password'] = md5($register_data['password']);
    $fields = '`' . implode('`, `', array_keys($register_data)) . '`'; 
    $data = '\'' . implode('\', \'', $register_data) . '\''; 
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `_users` ($fields) VALUES ($data)";
    $query = mysqli_query($dbCon, $sql);
}
```

How can I restrict the values entered for the form field named 'active' to 1 or 0? I have tried 1 and 0 without the apostrophes but I still get the error associated with this if statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a problem with your condition. Use `&&` instead of `||`:

```
if ($_POST['active'] != '1' && $_POST['active'] != '0')
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. However I can now  insert 00 and it will still work. Should I restrict the field values to single digits just to make sure? Also, could you please explain why && works instead of || ? I thought the correct approach was if x = 1 OR x = 0, instead of x = 1 AND x = 0 -> that last statement makes me think that both have to be true at the same time. Thank you

Comment: change != to !==. This will keep php from comparing the values as integers

Comment: Yes your approach is correct. But the condition you've written is not `x = 1` but `x != 1`. Hence, `x != 1 OR x != 0` would mean only one of those need to be true (which will always be the case - `(x isn't 1) OR (x isn't 0)`). What you need is a condition that says `(x isn't 1) AND (x isn't 0)`, hence the `&&`. 
You could also have written the condition as `!(x = 1 OR x = 0)`.

Comment: A logician would tell you, `not (P or Q)` is equivalent to saying `(not P) and (not Q)`.

Comment: @JohnBupit Hello John, could you maybe help me for a second time? I've stumbled across this error once more, the field works as expected only when entering 1 as value. Whenever I enter 0 it acts like the field is blank and the value is not registered in the database

Comment: Can you update the question with the updated code, and the relevant html form?

Comment: @JohnBupit, Thanks for the swift response. I have decided to use a checkbox instead, which seems to fit the purpose way better than the text field.